# Capistrano tasks not performing within the given scope.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I have build some capistrano tasks which I need to run on within the defined `:app` roles. This is what I have so far:

```
desc "Stop unicorn"
task :stop, :roles => :app do
  logger.info "Stopping unicorn server(s).."
  run "touch #{unicorn_pid}"
  pid = capture("cat #{unicorn_pid}").to_i
  run "kill -s QUIT #{pid}" if pid > 0
end
```

As far as I know, this should run the given commands on the servers given in the `:app` role, right? But the fact of the matter is that it's running the commands on the servers in the `:db` role.

Can anyone give some insight into this problem? Or is there a way to force Capistrano to adhere to the `:roles` flag?

Thanks in advance

// Emil

Comment: I have investigated a little more, and it turns out, that by the time it gets to this task, the `servers` array is including *all* the servers from all the roles (i.e. merged both `app`, `web`and `db`) is this expected behavior?

Comment: And further more. It seems that capture command is run on all servers, and then the kill command on all servers. This results in the kill command trying to kill the id of the last server on all the servers. Is there a best practice for this case, where I want to run a series of commands on a specific server, before iterating in the server array?

Comment: how is your environment-role-setup?

Comment: I found out that I could resolve my problem iterating through the `find_servers` array given by Capistrano it self. So it resolved it self, but I still don't think that it's the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using Capture will cause the task to be run only on the first server listed.

From the documentation:

The capture helper will execute the given command on the first matching server, and will return the output of the command as a string.

https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-DSL-Action-Inspection-Capture

Unfortunately I am facing a similar issue, the find_servers solution may work, but it's hacky, and runs N x N times, where N in the number of servers you have.